# Allow GridView sorting in Composite Control

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview, composite-controls

I can't figure out, how to enable sorting in dynamically created GridView placed in my Composite Control. Of course, I try to set property AllowSorting of GridView to "true", but it does not allow sorting functionality (there is no linkbutton in header on which I can click). AllowPaging property works just fine.

Any ideas how to resolve this?

```
protected override void OnInit(EventArgs e)
    {
        innerGridView.AutoGenerateColumns = false;
        innerGridView.AllowSorting = true;
        innerGridView.AllowPaging = true;
        innerGridView.PageSize = 2;

        base.OnInit(e);
    }
```

Comment: Does your datasource have a valid SortParameterName?

Comment: Yes, it does - when I bind my datasource to other gridview on my page (which is not in composite control) it works fine.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the only visible problem is, that there is no LinkButton generated in GridView HeaderRow. So I bypass it by setting onclick attribute to every cell in HeaderRow.

```
protected override void Render(HtmlTextWriter writer)
    {
        if (innerGridView.HeaderRow != null)
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < innerGridView.HeaderRow.Cells.Count; i++)
            {
                innerGridView.HeaderRow.Cells[i].Attributes["onclick"] =
                    Page.ClientScript.GetPostBackClientHyperlink(innerGridView, "Sort$" + InnerGridViewDataTable.Columns[i].Caption, true);
            }
        }

        base.Render(writer);
    }
```

Now I can click to header and sorting works. Of course, I will be glad if someone will come with better solution.